# How to generate an algebraically independent set over rational number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

> **Algebraic independence.**  In abstract algebra,  a subset ${\displaystyle S}$ of a field ${\displaystyle }$L is algebraically independent over a subfield ${\displaystyle }$K if the elements of ${\displaystyle }$S do not satisfy any non-trivial polynomial equation with coefficients in ${\displaystyle }$K

Over $\mathbb{Q}$, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is there an algorithm to generate an algebraically independent set whose cardinality is $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such algorithm would be

> **[Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem):** If $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are algebraic numbers which are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $e^{\alpha_1},\ldots,e^{\alpha_n}$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

which reduces the problem to finding lineraly independent algebraic numbers. And this can be done for example by taking $\{1, \sqrt[m]{2}^2, \sqrt[m]{2}^3,\ldots,\sqrt[m]{2}^{m-1}\}$ which [you can verify here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783252/linearly-independent-real-numbers-over-mathbbq).